# How do I add a Build-Host attribute to a JAR manifest using Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'm learning to use [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) by putting together a few simple build scripts as an exercise, and I'd like to put the current machine's hostname in the JAR manifest. I know I can set manifest properties using the following syntax:

```
jar { 
    manifest {
        attributes('Build-Host', 'foo')
    }
}
```

What I don't know, however, is the best way to get the hostname of the current machine. Does Gradle itself provide this to the script somehow? I've searched the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) and the [user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html) but haven't found anything.

Comment: It is kind of curious that hostname isn't in an environment variable by Unix convention. One method would be to wrap Gradle in something else like Jenkins that could populate an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle doesn't provide a public API for getting the hostname. You'll have to do it on your own, for example by calling Java's `InetAddress.localHost.hostName`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `buildConfigField` and the `BuildConfig` class on Android:

---

`build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    buildConfigField 'long', 'BUILD_DATE', System.currentTimeMillis() + 'L'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_HOST', '"' + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + '"'
}
```

---

`App.java`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
Log.i(TAG, "BuildHost:  " + BuildConfig.BUILD_HOST);
Log.i(TAG, "BuildDate:  " + df.format(new Date(BuildConfig.BUILD_DATE)));
Log.i(TAG, "LaunchTime: " + df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```